# Python: Decoding of Str not supported after concatinating 2 variable strings and a set string

Tags: python, string

I've been writing a program as part of a school course and decided to make it a bit more extensive than I needed to. So for the better part of 3 months I've been slowly adding stuff in an attempt to make the system output a file to save that is human readable.

I could save this all under one file as previous programs I've written have but I can only get better if I try. So I have the program take the users family name and date of arrival and use that as the file name. I have the program concatenate these variables (both strings) with ".txt" at the end and save this as a variable I then use to name the file I want to write to. Issue is it spits out the error that "decoding strings is not supported". Just for reference the program is made to get a booking for a hotel-like thing and spit out the price, arrival date, name etc. and just print it but as I've said I'm overambitious. Also I apologise about the bad code, just started to learn this year and a bit. Any help appreciated. Having to run it through Python 3.3.0:

```
#Comment Format
#
#Code
#
#Comment about above Code
from random import*
c_single = 47
c_double = 90
c_family = 250
discount = 10
VAT = 20
max_stay = 14
min_stay = 1
room_list = []
min_rooms = 1
max_rooms = 4
cost = 0

#Sets all needed variables that would need to be changed if the physical business changes (e.g. Increase in number of rooms, Longer Max stay allowed, Change to Pricing)

print("Cost of room:")
print("Single - £", c_single)
print("Double - £", c_double)
print("Family - £", c_family)

#Prints prices based on above variables

name = input("What is the family name --> ")
    arrival = input("Please enter date of arrival in the form dd/mm/yy --> ")
    while len(arrival) != 8:
        arrival = input("Please re-enter, in the case of the month or day not being 2 digits long insert a 0 before to insure the form dd/mm/yy is followed --> ")
#Gets the guests name and date of arrival for latter update into the business' preferred method of storage for bookings

nights = int(input("How many nights do you intend to stay in weeks --> "))
while nights > max_stay or nights < min_stay:
    nights = int(input("That is too short or long, please reneter stay in weeks -->"))
if nights >=  3:
    discount_aplic = 1

#Gets the guests ideal number of weeks stay, ensure that this would be possible then adds the discount if applicable
rooms = int(input("Please enter number of rooms required --> "))
while rooms < min_rooms or rooms > max_rooms:
    rooms = int(input("That number of rooms is unachievable in one purchase, please re-enter the number of rooms you require --> "))

#Gets number of rooms desired and checks that it does not exceed the maximum allowed by the business or the minimum (currently 1, staying no nights doesn't work)

for room in range (rooms):
    current_room = input("Please enter the room desired--> ")
    current_room = current_room.upper()
    if current_room == "SINGLE":
        cost += c_single
    elif current_room == "DOUBLE":
        cost += c_double
    elif current_room == "FAMILY":
        cost += c_family

    #Checks which room is desired

    else:
        while current_room != "SINGLE" and current_room != "DOUBLE" and current_room != "FAMILY":
            current_room = input("Invalid room type, valid entries are : single, double or family --> ")
            current_room = current_room.upper()

#Ensures that the desired room is valid, if first inserted not correctly, repeats until valid entry is entered

room_list.append (current_room)

#Adds the wanted room type to the array room_list

cost = cost * nights
#calculates cost
booking = randrange(1000,9999)

print("Name: ", name)
print("You have booked from ", arrival)
print("You have booked stay for ", nights, "weeks")
print("You have booked", rooms, " room/s of these categories;")
print(str(room_list))
print("This will cost £", cost)
print("Booking referral: ", booking)

#Prints booking information
dateStr = str(arrival)
storageFileName = str(dateStr, name,".txt")
storageFile = open(storageFileName, "w")
storageFile.write("Name: ", name)
storageFile.write("They have booked from ", arrival)
storageFile.write("They have booked stay for ", nights, "weeks")
storageFile.write("They have booked", rooms, " room/s of these categories;")
storageFile.write(str(room_list))
storageFile.write("This has cost them -- >£", cost)
storageFile.write("Booking referral: ", booking)
#saves the storage data to a server under the name and data.
```

Comment: Strange, I would expect this code to give `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on the `arival =` line, rather than `decoding strings is not supported`. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: In Python 3.x a string is encoded to bytes and bytes are decoded to a string.

Comment: str(dateStr, name, ".txt") -> "{}{}.txt".format(dateStr, name)

Comment: This is unrelated to your main problem, but the `current_room = current_room.upper` line in your `while` loop is missing a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Kevin, I have coppied it from my IDE but had to add the 4 space indent after so indendation may be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
storageFileName = str(dateStr, name,".txt")
```

Calling `str` with more than one argument will not convert each argument to a string and combine them. What you're actually doing here is calling str with the parameters `str(bytes_or_buffer, encoding, errors)`. According to the documentation:

```
>>> help(str)
Help on class str in module builtins:

class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
 |
 |  Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
 |  errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
 |  that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
 |  Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
 |  or repr(object).
 |  encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
 |  errors defaults to 'strict'.
```

Since you're specifying `encoding` and `errors`, the first argument can't be a string, because a string isn't a data buffer. This explains the error `decoding str is not supported`.

If you are trying to concatenate strings together, you should use the `+` operator, or the `format` method:

```
storageFileName = dateStr + name + ".txt"
```

Or

```
storageFileName = "{}{}.txt".format(dateStr, name)
```